# ArCGIS pro crashes when using addLayer or insertLayer

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro

I made a script which runs from ArcGIS geoprocessing tool. The script makes a output_layer.lyrx based on the operation selected by user and there is function `addtoproject()` used to add the output_layer in map. But that function works sometimes, most of the time arcGIS hangs and stop running. In geoprocessing progress bar for the script it is still 'running'. If I use `addtoproject()` function as a separate script it works without any problems.
**The code runs if I do the following: Find the result using this script and comment the addtoproject function.Copy the addtoproject function into a seperate .py file and run it seperately it will work.**
If I use the script below, it runs 2,3 times max after that I doesn't.

Here is the code:

```py
import arcpy as ar
#all paths
buildings_path = 'C:/Users/imvegita/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/DB_final/data/buildings.shp'
stop_points = 'C:/Users/imvegita/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/DB_final/data/Stops.shp'
project_path =  'C:/Users/imvegita/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/DB_final/DB_final.aprx'
out_path = 'C:/Users/imvegita/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/DB_final/data'
out_feature_layer_path = 'C:/Users/imvegita/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/DB_final/data/output_feature_layer.shp'
# final output file.
out_layer_file = r'C:/Users/imvegita/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/DB_final/data/result.lyrx'
gdb_path = 'C:/Users/imvegita/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/DB_final/DB_final.gdb/Route1'
# enables overwriting
ar.env.overwriteOutput = True

def addtoproject():
    aprx = ar.mp.ArcGISProject('Current')
    df = aprx.listMaps("*")[0]
    layers = df.listLayers("*")[0]
    # for rows in layers:
    #     print(rows)
    toAddLayer = ar.mp.LayerFile(#location of output file)
    # i tried both insertlayer and addlayer. None of them are working.
    df.addLayer(toAddLayer,"TOP")
    # df.insertLayer(layers, toAddLayer, "BEFORE")
    del aprx, df, layers, toAddLayer

def ListbyCategory(category):
    # making feature layer
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buildings_path, 'buildings_feature_layer')
    # updating feature layer for desired result
    if category =='All Buildings':
        pass
    elif category == 'Apartments':
        ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION',
                                             """ "building"='on campus apartments' OR "building"='off campus apartments' """)
    else:
        ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION',
                                             """ "building"='{}' """.format(category))

    # saving to disk
    ar.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('buildings_feature_layer', out_path, 'output_feature_layer')
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(out_feature_layer_path, 'result_layer')
    ar.SaveToLayerFile_management('result_layer', out_layer_file)

def Nearest(category, location1):
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buildings_path, 'buildings_feature_layer')
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buildings_path, 'temp_feature_layer')

    ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('temp_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION', """ "name"='{}' """.format(location1))
    if category == 'All Buildings':
        ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION')
    elif category == 'Apartments':
        ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION',
                                             """ "building"='on campus apartments' OR "building"='off campus apartments' """)
    else:
        ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION',
                                             """ "building"='{}' """.format(category))

    ar.Near_analysis('temp_feature_layer', 'buildings_feature_layer')

    ar.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('temp_feature_layer', out_path, 'output_feature_layer')
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(out_feature_layer_path, 'result_layer')
    ar.SaveToLayerFile_management('result_layer', out_layer_file)

    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(out_layer_file, 'output_layer')

    cursor = ar.SearchCursor('output_layer')
    for row in cursor:
        id = row.getValue('NEAR_FID')

    ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION', """ "FID"={} """.format(id))
    # # creating output
    ar.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('buildings_feature_layer', out_path, 'output_feature_layer')
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(out_feature_layer_path, 'result_layer')
    ar.SaveToLayerFile_management('result_layer', out_layer_file)

def Route(location1, location2):
    # if ar.Exists(gdb_path):
    #    ar.Delete_management(gdb_path)

    # making feature layer for all stop points
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(stop_points, 'stop_points_layer')

    # selecting the stops selected by user
    ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('stop_points_layer', "NEW_SELECTION",
                                         """ "name"='{}' OR "name"='{}' """.format(location1, location2))

    # save the selected stop points as feature class
    ar.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('stop_points_layer', out_path, 'selected_stop_points')

    route_object = ar.na.MakeRouteAnalysisLayer('https://www.arcgis.com/', "Route", 'Walking Distance')
    layer_object = route_object.getOutput(0)
    sublayer_names = ar.na.GetNAClassNames(layer_object)
    stops_layer_name = sublayer_names["Stops"]
    selected_stop_points_path = out_path + "/selected_stop_points.shp"
    ar.na.AddLocations(layer_object, stops_layer_name, selected_stop_points_path, "", "")
    ar.na.Solve(layer_object, "SKIP")
    layer_object.saveACopy(out_layer_file)


def SearchbyName(location1):
    # making feature layer
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buildings_path, 'buildings_feature_layer')

    # updating feature layer for desired result
    ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION',
                                         """ "name"='{}' """.format(location1))

    # saving to disk
    ar.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('buildings_feature_layer', out_path, 'output_feature_layer')
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(out_feature_layer_path, 'result_layer')
    ar.SaveToLayerFile_management('result_layer', out_layer_file)

def WithinXdistance(category, location1, distance):
    # making feature layer
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buildings_path, 'buildings_feature_layer')
    # making temp feature layer
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buildings_path, 'temp_feature_layer')

    # updating feature layer to select the building for which we need to find the surroundings
    ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('temp_feature_layer', 'NEW_SELECTION',
                                         """ "name"='{}' """.format(location1))

    # finding all building within x miles of above building
    ar.SelectLayerByLocation_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_GEODESIC', 'temp_feature_layer',
                                        '{}'.format(distance))

    # from above layer extracting buildings of only the requested category
    if category == 'All Buildings':
        pass
    elif category == 'Apartments':
        ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'SUBSET_SELECTION',
                                             """ "name"='{}' OR "building"='on campus apartments' OR "building"='off campus apartments' """.format(location1))
    else:
        ar.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('buildings_feature_layer', 'SUBSET_SELECTION',
                                         """ "name"='{}' OR "building"='{}' """.format(location1, category))

    # saving to disk
    ar.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('buildings_feature_layer', out_path, 'output_feature_layer')
    ar.MakeFeatureLayer_management(out_feature_layer_path, 'result_layer')
    ar.SaveToLayerFile_management('result_layer', out_layer_file)

def findResult(operation, category, location1, location2, distance):
    # ar.SetParameterAsText(5, operation)
    if operation == 'List by category':
        ListbyCategory(category)
    elif operation == 'Nearest':
        Nearest(category, location1)
    elif operation == 'Route/ Distance/ Directions':
        Route(location1, location2)
    elif operation == 'Search by name':
        SearchbyName(location1)
    else:
        # Within x distance operation
        WithinXdistance(category, location1, distance)

if __name__=='__main__': 
    operation = 'List by category'
    category = 'All Buildings'
    location1 = 'Geoscience'
    location2 = 'Library'
    distance = '0.1'

    findResult(operation, category, location1, location2, distance)
    # findResult computes the result and creates a output_layer
    addtoproject()
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: No. I just put the addlayer and insertlayer in try block and was running it in python, same thing, it was initially going in exception block and not it is running in python. But still error in arcGIS.

Comment: Also, now it is acting super weird and not adding the layer even once in arcGIS. But it is adding layer in python.

Comment: When writing a code snippet for presentation here I think you should remove your try/except statements and replace any GetParameterAsText lines with hardcoded example values.

Comment: I agree with @PolyGeo, you are not showing us the full code, may be the problem lies elsewhere? We can't answer that question as "#location of output file" is not a valid path, maybe it's a silly typo? Amend your question and add all code along with the actual inputs as requested.

Comment: Looking through a list of known issues, I see a few issues that have been fixed with `addLayer` in the upcoming version. Specifically with raster layers, basemap layers or if the bottom position is used. Can you confirm you're trying to add features and put them at the top (instead of bottom?) That would rule out a few known bugs I can see.

Comment: @PolyGeo hard coded the inputs.

Comment: @Hornbydd Added the entire code. Though i doubt that there are typos since the script are running fine separately.

Comment: @KHibma, I think I need to use top. I am actually trying to display the result when processing tools work is done. Though at this moment I won't mind anything if it just adds the layer to the project. Also i just tried bottom, even that is not working.

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to debug as although you have fulfilled our requests you have provided only *one* set of inputs and as I see it, it will only every execute operation = 'List by category' & category = 'All Buildings'. But as you say this seems to fail on subsequent runs, I assume with you changing inputs?

At this point my gut feeling is that on your subsequent runs you are providing inputs that do not create anything, e.g. it cannot solve the routing or your selections fail because the value does not exist. Hence your add to project function failing. Running it outside in another module will work because it's picking up on existing data from previous runs.

I note you have no logging, messaging or print statements. To get to the bottom of this you need to put in a whole load of these and watch the values and selections. For example your function `WithinXdistance()` does a spatial selection, well did it actually select anything? Might have worked fine for the first 2 runs but may be it is failing on the third? Won't know unless you report.

Comment: it is working and creating a output layer every time. And the result is also correct every time for all operations and all set of values. Just the addtoproject() is not working. So if I comment it and manually upload the output layer after running any operation, I get the correct output. And I know the error is at line df.addLayer(toAddLayer,"TOP"), because if i comment it, everything works fine. Also i put it in try except block, and it wasn't every time.

Comment: Also, if I run the it with same inputs the second time, it won't work in arcGIS pro. Though it might run in pycharm.

Comment: Try putting some sort of messaging before `df.addLayer(toAddLayer,"TOP")` to see if `toAddLayer` is actually a valid object? May be some sort of file system glitch means the layer object that it is returning is invalid?

Comment: What I am trying to do is insert the same layer again and again. Not working. It was successfully inserted the first time, after that it doesn't work.